# PayTM UPI Intent Integration - System Error

Tags: android, paytm, upi

I'm doing  App integration using PayTM "UPI Intent". Following below article.https://developer.paytm.com/docs/upi-solutions/integration/
When initiate transaction getting system error  00000900. Not sure what is the root cause. Also if you have a sample github code for "UPI Intent" integration please let me know.

'''
Step 1: Generated Signature using PaytmChecksum.generateSignature method
**Request:** {"requestType":"UNI_PAY","mid":"+PayTMMerchantID+","websiteName":"DEFAULT","orderId":"+ orderId +","txnAmount": {"value":"1.00","currency":"INR"},"userInfo":{"custId":"CUST_001"},"callbackUrl":"http://uuu.appspot.com/paytmCallback"};

**Response(Below is the signature from PayTM):** bpz8gRD8SH3wgTb2SX9SuIsepuUYff1+fTKi/FEGs4fiPOEf6JZpHGNUveIgGTzhobj7jyu+8l9fV5om73GV0is+Z0lelaPBBqEz/T9K7qc=

Step 2: Failed in Initiate Transaction:

Request: https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=GoaUJD89593901528729&orderId=2

Header Signature: bpz8gRD8SH3wgTb2SX9SuIsepuUYff1+fTKi/FEGs4fiPOEf6JZpHGNUveIgGTzhobj7jyu+8l9fV5om73GV0is+Z0lelaPBBqEz/T9K7qc=

Body: {                                       "requestType":"UNI_PAY",
                                        "mid":"GoaUJD89593901528729",
                                        "websiteName":"WEBSTAGING",
                                        "orderId":"2",
                                        "txnAmount":{
                                             "value":"1.00",
"currency":"INR"
},
"userInfo":{
"custId":"CUST_001"
},
"callbackUrl":"http://uuu.appspot.com/paytmCallback"
}

**Response (System Error):**                {
"head": {
"requestId": null,
"responseTimestamp": "1617373381292",
"version": "v1"
},
"body": {
"extraParamsMap": null,
"resultInfo": {
"resultStatus": "U",
"resultCode": "00000900",
"resultMsg": "System error"
}
}
}
'''

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Payment" in place of "UNI_PAY" in initiate transaction request. We advise you to raise a ticket to Paytm helpdesk through the portal.